# Plotting directed multigraphs in R

Tags: r, graph, plot

I've never used any graph plotting package in R, I'm  familiar with basic plotting commands and with `ggplot2` package. What I've found (but not tried out yet) are `Rgraphviz`, `network` and `igraph` packages. So I'd like to ask you, which package has simplest learning curve and satisfies following requirements:

- Has simple layout engines (spring layout, random, ...)
- Tries to draw multiple edges between two vertices so that they would not overlap. As a bonus it would be nice to being able to adjust this.
- Can draw loops.
- Vertex and edge labels, vertex and edge size and color are adjustable.
- (No need for any of the graph algorithms like link analysis, shortest path, max flow etc, but nice, if present)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [igraph](http://cneurocvs.rmki.kfki.hu/igraph/) package seems to fulfill your requirements, with the `tkplot()` function helping adjusting the final layout if needed.

Here is an example of use:

```
s <- cbind(A=sample(letters[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE),
           B=sample(letters[1:2], 100, replace=TRUE))
s.tab <- table(s[,1], s[,2])
library(igraph)
s.g <- graph.incidence(s.tab, weighted=T)
plot(s.g, layout=layout.circle, 
     vertex.label=c(letters[1:4],letters[2:1]),     
     vertex.color=c(rep("red",4),rep("blue",2)), 
     edge.width=c(s.tab)/3, vertex.size=20, 
     vertex.label.cex=3, vertex.label.color="white")
```

[image]

With the interactive display (there's a possibility of using `rgl` for 3D display), it looks like (I have slightly moved one vertex afterwards):

```
tkplot(s.g, layout=layout.circle, vertex.color=c(rep("red",4),rep("blue",2)))
```

[image]

Finally, you can even export you graph into most common format, like `dot` for graphviz.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try igraph out, when I need to plot graphs again! Just for infos, I went with RGraphviz after I asked the question and got away from the requirement of drawing multiple edges by reformulating my original task a bit.

Comment: @Timo Good to hear you found your way with graphviz. I use it a lot too. It's just `igraph` is most powerful, IMO. (btw, my +1 to your Q, I was out of votes when I answered :-)

Answer (score 2):

The [multigraph](https://github.com/mplex/multigraph/) R package can be useful as well. For the above example `bmgraph` plots such graph:

```
library("multigraph")
bmgraph(s.tab, layout = "circ", pch = 16:16, pos = 0, vcol = 6:7, lwd = 3, cex = 9)
```

[image]

And for a directed version:

```
bmgraph(s.tab, "circ", pch = 16:16, pos = 0, vcol = 6:7, lwd = 3, cex = 9, directed = TRUE)
```

[image]